# Casting a dynamic type in C# to F#

Tags: f#, auth0

I am working through Auth0's documentation [here](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-functions/) and porting the C# code to F#

In the C# code, there is this line:

```
var auth0LoginResult = await _auth0Client.LoginAsync(new { audience = AuthenticationConfig.Audience });
```

Where LoginAsync's parameter is called extraParameters of type object.

Audience is just a string, but when I try and pass in a string like this

```
let extraParameters = Support.authenticationConfig.Audience
let result = client.LoginAsync(extraParameters).Result
```

it fails with a

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters
>   specified does not match the expected number.

How can I pass in a type that the method likes?  Just cast it to object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the library takes an `object` and uses reflection to look at the members of the object, which is why the C# way of calling it is to give it an anonymous object as an argument.

In F#, you probably need to define an explicit record type with the parameters you need to pass as fields, although in the near future, you will likely be able to use [anonymous records for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/4499).

I have not tested this, but I would try something like this:

```
type LoginParameters = { audience : string }

async { 
  let! result = 
    auth0Client.LoginAsync({ audience = AuthenticationConfig.Audience }) 
    |> Async.AwaitTask
  (...) }
```